# Run a ASP.Net 3.5 site with some pages written in classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic

We have a site and a logged in section of the site that all was written in classic asp.  We are starting to convert the site pages to asp.net 3.5.  We are starting with the easiest pages (text mainly) first then we will rewrite the web application part of the site.

My question is - Is it possible to run the new asp.net 3.5 pages with classic asp pages?  Or will we need to rewrite everything before deploying?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It will work fine. Be warned, however: Sessions are not automatically ported between Classic ASP and .NET.